# Convert Irish Grid (Northings & Eastings) to Correct Northings & Eastings

Tags: python, pandas, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I have a CSV file that has columns for Latitude and Longitude. The data for each is in the Irish Grid Coordinate System (Northings & Eastings). How do I convert to correct latitude and longitude?

Example of what I have `Latitude 372000   Longitude 332000`.

Code

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("File.csv", skiprows=0, low_memory=False, encoding='ANSI')

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry)   

#this is a simple map that goes with geopandas
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), color='red', markersize=1.5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Irish Grid uses CRS 29903 (as per https://georepository.com/crs_29903/TM75-Irish-Grid.html), while the world file that comes with GeoPandas uses CRS 4326.    So you either have to reproject the first to the second, or vice versa.

Something like:

```
gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)
```

or

```
world = world.to_crs(29903)
```

you can then check this with (using Jupyter here):

```
In: world.crs

Out:
```

> 

> Name: TM75 / Irish Grid
> Axis Info [cartesian]:
>
> - E[east]: Easting (metre)
> - N[north]: Northing (metre)
>   Area of Use:
> - name: Europe - Ireland (Republic and Ulster) - onshore
> - bounds: (-10.56, 51.39, -5.34, 55.43)
>   Coordinate Operation:
> - name: Irish Grid
> - method: Transverse Mercator
>   Datum: Geodetic Datum of 1965
> - Ellipsoid: Airy Modified 1849
> - Prime Meridian: Greenwich

So putting this all together (assuming that the implicit CRS of your .csv is really 29903, it would look like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("File.csv", skiprows=0, low_memory=False, encoding='ANSI')
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])]
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry, crs= 29903) 
gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
gdf.plot(ax=world.plot(figsize=(10, 6)), color='red', markersize=1.5)
```

And you get geometry values that look like this:

```
0       POINT (-6.45067 53.35318)
1       POINT (-6.44943 53.35470)
2       POINT (-6.44432 53.35355)
3       POINT (-6.43974 53.34900)
4       POINT (-6.44179 53.34956)
```

[image]

Comment: You've lost me sorry. I'm very new to this. Where would I put "gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326)" in the code I have written?

Comment: Ah - sorry to be unclear - that would go after gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry).    So you bring in the GeoDataFrame as you've done, and then in order to prepare it to use with the world GDF, which has a different CRS, you do gdf = gdf.to_crs(4326).

Comment: I put it in after it and it gave me "ValueError: Cannot transform naive geometries.  Please set a crs on the object first."

Comment: Ah - so when you initialize the Irish data let's try:
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=geometry, crs= 29903)
The issue is that when you create a gdf from raw data (as opposed to a shapefile) it doesn't know what CRS you're using, so then when you try to reproject it, geopandas is confused because it has to reproject from some CRS.   Think of reprojection as analogous to language translation - if you don't know what language the original text is in, you can't translate it.

Comment: It ran and plotted a map, however the points didn't move from their original position.

Comment: Okay, can you update your original question with more specificity about what you're doing?   It's not clear yet if you just want the Irish data to be converted to long/lat or if you want to plot it alongside the world data.    No worries, my friend - this is par for the course when it comes to GIS.

Comment: Sure, well I have a CSV file. In it there is two columns. One is Latitude and the other is  Longitude. The number in these columns at 6 digits long. An example of this is Latitude 372000 and Longitude 332000. When I push these into geopanda they place points wayyyy beyond where the default  'naturalearth_lowres' map sits.

Comment: So the numbers are not normal latitude and longitude numbers. They are in fact Irish Grid Coordinate System numbers or Northings & Eastings. I need to somehow use script to convert them to normal latitude and longitude and then plot the points where they would be so they align correctly with the map ( which will naturally be in the correct location because of the geopandas coding)

Comment: Okay - I grabbed some Irish data and tried it out - updated my code to demonstrate more fully the steps.

Comment: Thank you. . . . :)